# How to open older .imovieproject files (folders) in iMovie '09

Tags: imovie

How do I open older .imovieproject files (they're actually folders folders) in iMovie '09?
I don't want to import the assets of the old project, I want the actual project to open on iMovie '09.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, actually. iMovie '08 and subsequent versions are a completely different program from iMovie HD 6 and previous versions.

However, the last released version of iMovie HD does still run on modern Macs. It used to be a free download for users of iLife '08, but Apple has since removed it (IMHO, to "encourage" power users to upgrade to Final Cut Express, since iMovie '08 was utterly useless if you happened to have been one of the few who knew what they were doing).

It is still possible to download and install iMovie HD through some avenues of questionable legality.

Comment: Ok, downloading... Is it possible to export the project from iMovie HD to something that iMovie 08 will open?

Comment: @Rafael Unfortunately no. You can export the finished product, or, like you saw, import the raw clips and then remake the project in the new version.

Comment: Wow, that sucks! How can they release a program that totally ignores saved files from older version of the program!?? That's just BS from Apple.

Comment: @Rafael Like I said, it's a completely different program. I guess having a timeline that advances by frame is too complicated for us mere mortals to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Had this question myself since I couldn't get the folder to be registered right due to the incompatibility.  Then I realized the "Media" folder in my .IMovieProject folder contained an MOV file I could just re-use in a new project.  Shame to loose my minimal editing, but at least I have something.